# Debugging a map reduce job in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to make some modification to the map reduce framework of Hadoop. For this, I imported the hadoop project into Eclipse. Now,I want to set up a map reduce application, such as Word Count and I want to debug it in Eclipse. I want to know which all portions of the Hadoop code are run while executing a map reduce task. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: What do you mean "which all portions of the Hadoop code are run"?

Comment: I want to know when the Scheduler is invoked, basically, I want to understand the internal working of the code.

Comment: I am not trying to check whether a map reduce job is working properly. I want to check the internal code of Hadoop which gets executed when a map reduce task is being executed. Please do help.